# Meteor autoform - compute value for hidden field

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

In a meteor autoform (using the classic aldeed package: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform), I have a hidden field called `'score'` whose value is a function of another field called `'optionID'`.

```
{{#autoForm
  class                = "autoform"
  id                   = dataID
  collection           = (getCollection 'DataColl')
  doc                  = dataDoc
  type                 = "method-update"
  meteormethod         = "DataColl.autoformUpsert"
  singleMethodArgument = true
  autosave             = true
}}

  {{> afQuickField
    name         = 'optionID'
    type         = "select-radio"
    template     = "buttonGroup"
    options      = scoreOptions
  }}

  {{> afQuickField
    name         = 'score'
    type         = "hidden"
    value        = selectedOptionScore
  }}

{{/autoform}}
```

The function `selectedOptionScore` depends on the selected value of 'optionID' (using `Autoform.getFieldValue`)

```
Template.formTemplate.helpers({
  selectedOptionScore(): String {
    const optionID = AutoForm.getFieldValue('optionID');
    const optionScore = someFunction(optionID);
    return optionScore;
  },
});
```

The problem is that on each autosave of the form, the value of `'score'` is "one change behind" the value of `'optionID'`, meaning the function computing `'score'` is correct, but the save to mongo seems to have happened before the `'score'` value was updated, so in mongo, `'score'` has the value of whatever it was right before `'optionID'` last changed.

For example, if I make `'score'` not hidden such that I can modify it, modifying it directly in the webpage will make its value reflected correctly in mongo. But modifying `'optionID'` in the webpage yields the "one change behind" behavior.

Is there a way to make a meteor autoform field depend on another field in the same form, without having it "lag behind" the autosave by one change always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a Template helper to calculate the value of your hidden `score` field, you might want to look into using a [autoform hook](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks). So instead of using your `selectedOptionScore` Template helper, you would define a hook like:

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['your-form-id'], {
  before: {
    method-update(doc) {
      doc.score = someFunction(doc.optionID);
      return doc;
    }
  }
});
```

This way just before your form is saved the calculated score is set, and saved with everything else.

Comment: Perfect. Actually this is precisely what I did to resolve it. And as a heads up for anyone seeing this, I think autovalues would also have been good, if my schema had been specific enough.